# Seleccionar valor por ComboBox, que se genere un calculo de cantidad y me lo imprima al resultado por un Label C# + SQL + WF

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, combobox, label

Esta es mi pantalla de Stock, lo que necesito es que si yo filtro en el ComboBox por un determinado producto me cuenta y muestre por el label cual es el total de Stock de dicho Producto.

En SQL, la consulta seria...

```
From Articulo
Where Producto = 'SPLIT INVERTER DAIKIN'

conn.Open();
string QueryStock = "Select sum(Cantidad) From Articulo Where Producto = @Producto";
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(QueryStock, conn);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", CbFiltrarProducto.SelectedValue.ToString());
comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
var value = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
lblStock.Text = value.ToString();
conn.Close();
```

Buscando por google y viendo ideas parecidas logre armar esto, pero aun no logre que funcione, espero puedan ayudarme. Desde ya muchas gracias, atte. Manuel

Comment: Donde declaras el objeto conn?

Comment: Hola Manuel, posdrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, y en caso de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
string QueryStock = "Select sum(Cantidad) as cantidad From Articulo Where Producto = @Producto";
SqlDataConnection conn = new SqlDataConnection(cadena_de_conexion);
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(QueryStock, conn);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", CbFiltrarProducto.Text);
comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

try
{
   conn.Open();
   SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

   if (reader.Read())
   {
      lblStock.Text = reader["cantidad"].ToString(); 
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Se ha producido una excepción");
}
finally
{
   conn.Close();
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es declarar la **variable QueryStock** que almacena la **consulta Sql**, creamos la conexión con la **cadena de conexión** tuya, posteriormente configuramos el **parámetro @Producto** con su correspondiente valor que seria obtenido del texto de un **ComboBox** y mediante la siguiente instrucción:

comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Decimos que vamos a trabajar con una **instrucción Sql**, ya que también podríamos trabajar con un **procedimiento almacenado** en cuyo caso tendríamos que poner:

```
comando.CommandType = CommandType. StoredProcedure;
```

Posteriormente **abrimos la conexión** y creamos un **DataReader** para obtener el resultado de la consulta que en este caso es un solo registro con una única columna, es decir la consulta solo nos devuelve un valor, este valor lo leemos y lo mostramos  en el **Label**.

Todo este código lo encerramos en un **bloque try-catch-finally**, para asegurarnos de que en caso que ocurra una excepción se nos muestre un mensaje y garantizar además que la conexión siempre quede cerrada.